# how to delete key from hash of array reference in perl

Tags: perl

I would like to delete a key from a hash of array reference:

if the "key" which I want to delete is 'Test', I tried something like

```
$Test = 'Test';

foreach my $k (keys %{$line}) {
     @{$line->{$k}} = grep @{$line->{'$Test'}} != 0, @{$line->{$k}};
}
```

But I could not remove it! Could someone tell me how to remove it?

Comment: It's not obvious how `$line` lokks like and what your plan exactly is. You should write a complete example, preferably with sample output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The perl `delete` operation does this.  See the [`perlfunc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) manual:

> delete *EXPR*
>
> Given an expression that specifies a hash element, array element, hash slice, or array slice, deletes the specified element(s) from the hash or array.  In the case of an array, if the array elements happen to be at the end, the size of the array will shrink to the highest element that tests true for exists() (or 0 if no such element exists).

It is discussed here:

- [How do I completely remove a key/value pair from my hash?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=4685)
- [5.3. Deleting from a Hash](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch05_04.htm)
- [How should I delete hash elements while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989182/how-should-i-delete-hash-elements-while-iterating)

Comment: I tried:    for my $k (keys %{$line}) { if ($k =~ m/$Test/){delete @{$line->{$Test}};}else{next;}} But did not work. I got delete argument is not a HASH or ARRAY element or slice at  ...

Comment: The `delete` would be applied to something like `${$line}{$k}`, since that is the hash name/value I understood you were deleting.  The `@` indicates an array variable, while `%{$line}` is a hash variable.